# Xcode Constraints causing image to enlarge to 1920 x 1920

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

How it appears in Xcode:

[image]

It's got content compression resistance priority of h:750 v:750, content hugging priority of h:251 v:251, trailing / leading space of 5, width and height equals to 390, top space of 40, and a 1:1 ratio.

EDIT: I'm using Auto-layout.

There are other elements that rely on it, but I'd rather get it displaying properly first.

Here's how it looks like in the iPhone 6 Simulator:

[image]

Comment: as i see from the screenshot,there are issues with the constraints. Are they solved?

Comment: I think you have to many constrains on this UIImageView that affect image width.  You should have a leading, trailing, top space, ratio, and the image will enlarge to device width, and height equal to width

Comment: Why do you need width and height constraints if you want your image resized?

Comment: @T_77, it's the scrollview - ambiguous scrollable content. Not sure how to fix that - centerX and Y, perhaps?

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Comment: @T_77, yes, I am, sorry if I didn't mention that earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have too many constraints set which conflict with each other. In particular fixing the width and the leading and trailing at the same time will conflict. So will setting the height and the top/bottom conflict. You are probably getting an error in the console telling you it has had to break some constraints.

If you want the image positioned as per your post and to grow with 1:1 to fill either width or height all you should need is:

- Set the leading constraint to 5.
- Set the top constraint to 40.
- Set the trailing to be >= 5.
- Set the bottom to be >= 5.
- Set the aspect ration to be 1:1

This is saying that you want the image 40 from the top, and a margin of at least 5 on the right and bottom and an aspect of 1:1. The image view will grow to fit based on the constraint which limits its growth: normally the right in portrait or the bottom in landscape.

You should not set the width or height unless you want to fix or limit it. However if you do that you can not set trailing or bottom.

The image inside will show based on how you have set the image view to present the image: apsect fit, aspect fill etc...

**Updated**

I just noticed you have the image in a scroll view. I think you need to put the image view in a view which you give a defined size then add that to the scroll view. You may need to do that in code to deal with multiple devices. The scroll view needs to know the content size of the content view. See this tech note: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: I did as above, other than the bottom >= 5 as other UIViews depend on it, and putting the image in a scroll view. I did need to set a constraint on the last UIView, set to the bottom of the scrollview to get it scrolling. Seems to work both on iPhone 5s and iPhone 6 simulators so far.